# Multiple threads accessing a websocket

Tags: .net-core, websocket, thread-safety

I have multiple threads trying to write to a websocket at the same time. What would be the best concurrency mechanism to use when accessing websocket from multiple threads?

Each thread sends a message on a websocket and then waits for a single response.
I keep getting an error:

> There is already one outstanding 'ReceiveAsync' call for this
> WebSocket instance. ReceiveAsync and SendAsync can be called
> simultaneously, but at most one outstanding operation for each of them
> is allowed at the same time.

Relevant code (without any concurrency mechanism in place)

```
// multiple trackers are calling in 
// for each tracker a thread is started calling this method
public static void SendPackageToClients(GpsTrackerEntry gte)
{

    var gteByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gte));

    foreach (var cs in AsynchronousSocketListener.carSubscriptions[gte.carId])
    {

        if (cs.Value.ws.State != WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            UnsubscribeClient(cs.Key);
            continue;
        }

        Task.Run( () => {
            // TODO: ideally here a thread should stop and wait for 
            // the target websocket to become available (i.e. no send or 
            // receive is being performed) and then execute the following method

            SendPackageToClient(cs.Value.ws, gteByteArray, cs.Key);
        });

    }
    return;
}

private static async void SendPackageToClient(WebSocket ws, byte[] gteByteArray, int key)
{

    try
    {

        await ws.SendAsync(gteByteArray, 0, true, CancellationToken.None);

        var timeOut = new CancellationTokenSource(5000).Token;

        byte[] ping = new byte[10];

        var result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(ping, timeOut);

        if (result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" **** CLIENT CLOSED CONNECTION **** ");
            UnsubscribeClient(key);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" **** SERVER ERROR **** " + ex.Message);
        UnsubscribeClient(key);
    }
}
```

I have tried using Monitor.Enter(cs.Value.ws) and SemaphoreSlim, but just can't seem to have it setup correctly

Comment: Use SemaphoreSlim to limit the number of writers to just 1 at any time.

Comment: Thx for response. Could you possibly add simple implementation how would solution with SemaphoreSlim look like. Since i tried SemaphoreSlim and it didn't yield the desired effect. If its easier i can add my solution using SemaphoreSlim

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve to problem. Ended up using SemaphoreSlim, added a semaphoreSlim for each websocket and checked it before calling SendPackageToClient. Also i had to return a value from SendPackageToClient so i could await for it to finish and then release the semaphore.

Thx @Lasse V. Karlsen